# I am trying to find a way to handle error 1062 of duplicate entries of '1' for key 'movieID'

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

I am trying to find a way to have duplicate value for key 1 to store in multiple genre for movieID.

I already tried auto increment on the table but still had those errors

CREATE TABLE movie_genres (
movieID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
genre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (movieID),
FOREIGN KEY (movieID) REFERENCES movies(ID)
);

ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'movieID'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `movie`.`movie_genres` (`movieID`, `genre`) VALUES ('1', 'Animation')

ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'movieID'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `movie`.`movie_genres` (`movieID`, `genre`) VALUES ('1', 'Children')

ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'movieID'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `movie`.`movie_genres` (`movieID`, `genre`) VALUES ('1', 'Comedy')

ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'movieID'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `movie`.`movie_genres` (`movieID`, `genre`) VALUES ('1', 'Fantasy')

Comment: Your design is wrong, you should not have a reference to a movie in your genre table. Each genre should have its own id. One movie has many genre and many movies share the same genre so it’s a many to many relationship

Answer (score 1):

Your database design has some fundamental problems, in particular it is missing a junction table which relates movies to their genres (1 to n).  Here is one proposal for what your schema might be:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE genres (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    genre VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE movie_genres (
    movieID INT NOT NULL,
    genreID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (movieID, genreID)
);
```

Now with this schema in place, here is what your inserts might look like:

```
INSERT INTO movies (ID, title) VALUES (1, 'Avatar');

INSERT INTO genres (ID, genre)
VALUES
   (1, 'Animation'), (2, 'Children'), (3, 'Comedy'), (4, 'Fantasy');

INSERT INTO movie_genres (movieID, genreID)
VALUES
    (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4);
```

The basic idea here is that the movies and genres tables exist only to keep track of...movies and genres.  They don't "know" anything about each other.  To handle the relationships between movies and genres, your updated `movie_genres` table comes into play.  It stores only the IDs from the movies and their corresponding genres.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my schema looks like:
CREATE TABLE movies (
id      INT NOT NULL,
title   VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
imdbID  VARCHAR(30),
spanishTitle    VARCHAR(180),
imdbPictureURL  VARCHAR(2200),
year        VARCHAR(5),
rtID            VARCHAR(150),
rtAllCriticsRating  INT,
rtAllCriticsNumReviews  INT,
rtAllCriticsNumFresh    INT,
rtAllCriticsNumRotten   INT,
rtAllCriticsScore   INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
CREATE TABLE movie_genres (
movieID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
genre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (movieID),
FOREIGN KEY (movieID) REFERENCES movies(ID)
);